# Case statement in Join Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get data from multiple tables but not sure how to do that. Below is a query which I am using but its not working. Please suggest.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        VWL.Type, VWL.ID AS CompanyID,VWL.Name
    FROM dbo.LeadList_New AS VWL 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        CASE VWL.Type WHEN 'COMPANY' THEN
            CRMCompanyEmailAddress AS CE ON VWL.ID=CE.CRMCompanyID
        WHEN 'PERSON' THEN
            PersonEmailAddress AS PE ON VWL.ID=PE.PersonID
        END
```

Comment: Any particular SQL statement has to have a particular "shape" - which tables, columns, etc are involved, their types, etc. The only way to change which *tables* are included in a query would be to construct it as a string (dynamic SQL). That being said, it's unclear to me what you're trying to achieve - you're doing a distinct on columns to the `LEFT` of the join, and selecting no columns from the `RIGHT` - the entire query's result will be the same even if no join occurs at all. Could you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Please add in description an example of data in tables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot join tables with a `CASE`, maybe you want this instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT VWL.Type, VWL.ID AS CompanyID, VWL.Name, 
                CASE WHEN VWL.type = 'COMPANY' 
                    THEN CE.Name 
                    ELSE PE.Name 
                END AS EntityName 
FROM   dbo.leadlist_new AS VWL 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN crmcompanyemailaddress AS CE 
                    ON VWL.id = CE.crmcompanyid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN personemailaddress AS PE 
                    ON VWL.id = PE.personid
```

Answer (score 3):

You should move CASE statement into the SELECT body:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
         VWL.Type, VWL.ID AS CompanyID,VWL.Name

        case VWL.Type 
              when 'COMPANY' then  CE.Address
              when 'PERSON' then PE.Address
        end


FROM        dbo.LeadList_New AS VWL  
LEFT OUTER JOIN CRMCompanyEmailAddress as CE on VWL.ID=CE.CRMCompanyID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PersonEmailAddress as PE on VWL.ID=PE.PersonID
```

Or just UNION two statements for Company and Person

```
SELECT VWL.Type, VWL.ID AS CompanyID,VWL.Name,CE.Address as Address 
FROM        dbo.LeadList_New AS VWL  
LEFT OUTER JOIN CRMCompanyEmailAddress as CE on VWL.ID=CE.CRMCompanyID
WHERE VWL.Type='COMPANY'

UNION

SELECT VWL.Type, VWL.ID AS CompanyID,VWL.Name,PE.Address as Address
FROM        dbo.LeadList_New AS VWL  
LEFT OUTER JOIN PersonEmailAddress as PE on VWL.ID=PE.PersonID
WHERE VWL.Type='PERSON'
```

Comment: UNION is the best option in my opinion. Maybe using UNION ALL instead.

Comment: @Dd2 The topic starter needs DISTINCT rows so I used UNION to eliminate all dublicates