# Conditional LEFT JOIN clause SQL Server where conditionality in second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have a view (`v_Flat_DemogTDComps`) which contains the following fields (among others)

```
PatientID     Integer
[Start date]  DateTime
SystemicStart DateTime
```

I also have a table (`Operation`) with:

```
PatientID                Integer
[Operation/Reason Date]  DateTime
[Surgical]               Boolean
[Operation/Reason Name]  String
```

I want to LEFT JOIN `v_Flat_DemogTDComps` ON `Operation` where:

1. `PatientID = PatientID AND`
2. (
   If [Surgical] = 1 THEN [Operation/Reason Date] = SystemicStart OR
    If [Surgical] = 0 THEN [Operation/Reason Date] = [Start Date]
   )

Ultimately, I want to SELECT everything in `v_Flat_DemogTDComps` along with [`Operation/Reason Name`]

I've tried using this solution and thought about creating two Views of Operation (one where `Surgical=1` and one where `Surgical=0`): [Case statement in Join Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907300/case-statement-in-join-clause)

However this only seems to work where the conditional part is in the first table. There is nothing in `v_Flat_DemogTDComps` which can determine whether I should use one View of Operation over another.

How do I JOIN when the conditional clause is in the second table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Or` and `And` operator to simulate `If else`. Try this.

```
ON v_Flat_DemogTDComps.PatientID = Operation.PatientID
AND ( ( [Surgical] = 1
        AND [Operation/Reason Date] = SystemicStart )
        OR ( [Surgical] = 0
            AND [Operation/Reason Date] = [Start Date] ) )
```

Comment: I've tried this as well but it only returns values where Surgical = 0 and the rest are null.

Comment: @Matthew can you sample data and desired output.

Comment: Silly mistake - SystemicStart had actual times recorded whereas the other three DateTime fields simply had 00:00:00.000. Your solution worked after using CONVERT() on the relevant fields.